# CRS setting in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-3

I'm working with this CRS: "EPSG:32632 - WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N - Projected" in a Qgis3.4 (long term release) version. When I try to add a raster file with this CRS:"EPSG:25833, ETRS 1989 UTM Zone 33N" it doesn't overlay properly with the other layers. What I did is to polygonize the raster and then converting the resulting vector layer into another CRS (by export and save as ESRI shapefile). Nothing again.

This Qgis version has the 'On the fly' enabled by default.

Any help or ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the original CRS of the raster is EPSG 25833?

Comment: Checked out properly. This should be the right CRS: "ETRS89/ETRS-TM33 ", but now I cannot find this CRS in the Qgis List, so I got another problem...

Answer (score 1):

When you know the name of your CRS but not its EPSG code, and you can't find a CRS with the same name in QGIS, use https://spatialreference.org to find the EPSG code.

According to [spatialreference.org](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/etrs89-etrs-tm33/), the CRS, "ETRS89/ETRS-TM33," is EPSG:3045. In QGIS, EPSG:3045 is called "ETRS89 / UTM zone 33N (N-E)."